# Rapidly decaying functions and uniform convergence of their periodic version

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, distribution-theory

I've been wasting my entire morning trying to understand a simple, short paragraph from Stein-Weiss, *Introduction to Fourier Analysis in Euclidean spaces* and I've miserably failed so far. Could you please help me and shed some light?

The ingredients of the failure: $f \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function with sufficiently fast decay at infinity, i.e.
$$
|f(y)| \le C(1+|y|)^{-n-\delta}, \qquad \text{ for some } \delta >0 
$$
(say, for every $y$) and we assume that its Fourier transform has the same decay property. (A very easy case I've been considering is if $f$ is in the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space))

Then the authors introduce the periodised version of $f$, defined as
$$\tag{*}\label{periodicas}
x \mapsto \sum_{z \in \mathbb Z^n} f(x+z)
$$
and they claim:

> By comparison with $\sum_{z \in \mathbb Z^n}(1+|z|)^{-n-\delta}$, we see that \eqref{periodicas} is a uniformly convergent series whose terms are continuous functions.

Thus the function in \eqref{periodicas} would be shown to be continuous.

Now, there is no doubt that the terms in the sum are continuous functions, nor do I have any problems in remembering that uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. The issue is the *uniform* convergence. How is that obtained? Some sort of $M$-test or comparison criterion? By assumption we have
$$
|f(x+z)| \le \frac{C}{(1+|x+z|)^{n+\delta}}
$$
but it is not quite clear to me how to manipulate the RHS and get rid of that $x$... any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the inequality
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
1+|x+z|\ge (1+|z|)(1+|x|)^{-1}
\end{equation}
to show
$$
\sup_{x\in[0,1)^n}|f(x+z)| \le \sup_{x\in[0,1)^n}C(\frac{1+|x|}{1+|z|})^{n+\delta}\le C'\frac{1}{(1+|z|)^{n+\delta}}.
$$
By the $M$-test, the series $\sum_{z\in\mathbb Z^n}f(x+z)$ is uniformly convergent in $x\in[0,1)^n$.

---

To prove $(1)$, use the triangle inequality:
\begin{align*}
1+|z| &\le 1+|z-(-x)|+|\!-\!x|\\
&=1+|z+x|+|x|\\
&\le(1+|z+x|)(1+|x|).
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh, that is a cool inequality - a very nice way to conclude! Does that inequality have any geometric meaning? I do not see a completely trivial proof of that one, am I missing something obvious? Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Romeo: I updated my answer with the details. It is just an application of the triangle inequality.

Comment: Ah sure, that's true - so simple! Awesome, thank you again for your answer, very appreciated.